# AttributeError: 'Downloader' object has no attribute '_PlaylistDownloader__server' (attribute concatenation problem)

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, tornado

I'm looking to get the parent (set in __init_class method) server object but the compiler seems to change my code.

I tried to give the actual server object in parent but another error pops. I'm using websocket tornado.

```
self.__parent.__server.send_to(ws_id, {
      "downloading":artistTrack + " - " + nameTrack,
      "number":index,
      "on":str(len(self.__tracks))
})
```

The error is "AttributeError: 'Downloader' object has no attribute '_PlaylistDownloader__server'" but it should send a message with the __server object. I really don't know where to search to resolve this kind of issues. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Double underscore names are private, not protected, via name mangling. Use a single leading underscore.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank's a lot ! It was such a stupid mistake, but i don't know how to put the question in solved so...

Comment: @Miklere If your problem is solved then please post an answer and accept your answer to close the question.